# Convert string MM/dd/yyyy hh/mm/ss tt to datetime MM/dd/yyyy hh/mm/ss tt

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I want to convert a string that has the format `MM/dd/yyyy hh/mm/ss tt` to datetime with the same format

I tried:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("05/16/2019 10/30/15 AM", "MM/dd/yyyy hh/mm/ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But it returns `16/05/2019 10:30:15` instead of `05/16/2019 10/30/15 AM`

Comment: "to datetime with the same format" - `DateTime` doesn't *have* a format, any more than (say) `int` does. Just as there's no such thing as "hex int" vs a "decimal int", at `DateTime` value is *just a date and time*, with no formatting.

Comment: What you want to do is a two step operation. `DateTime.Parse` (and `.ParseExact`) will parse a string, returning a `DateTime`. To get that back to a string (possibly of a specific format), you need a call to `DateTime.ToString`

Comment: you need to parse date first and then format it using desired format string. I.e. `date.ToString(....)`

Comment: so in the end the result will still be a string?

Comment: Depends. What do you want to do with it? If you need a (specific) format, then yes, it's going to be a string. If you are going to do calculations, then you will probably want to use DateTime and format the result of those.

Comment: @Fildor I'll save the date with that format in a database. So I'll just use varchar instead of datetime in the database.